# jquery autocomplete custom data JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, autocomplete

I'm using  [jquery autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete). I've this requirement where the user types in the textbox and a dropdown appears which shows the name of employees which contains that character and as they type the list becomes more condensed.

When the user selects an employee its emp_id,emp_email etc will be sent to the controller for further processing.

This employee info are stored in a Hashmap like this :

```
// 001 is emp id, Aaron Gonsalves is the display name 
and Aaron@email.com is the email id

empMap("1","001:Aaron Gonsalves:Aaron@email.com");    
empMap("2","002:Abraham Gonsalves:Abraham@email.com");
empMap("3","003:Ackon Gonsalves:Ackon@email.com");
```

I know that jquery supports key value pair but for that I've to use json (I guess so) for fetching the info and send it to the autocomplete. Anyway I can't use json in my project.

For the UI I'm using following piece of code

```
 // This logic is working fine when <%=empMap> 
 // contains data like "Aaron Gonsalves,Abraham Gonsalves,Ackon Gonsalves"
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var data = "<%=empMap>".split(","); 
     $("#example").autocomplete(data);  // #example is my text box id
 });
```

Is there any way of internally split the data on basis of ":" and display the emp_name in my dropdown and sending the emp_id and email to the controller by means of a hidden field?

Please help me with some code, I'm totally new in jquery and I've very minimal knowledge in it.

For your info I'm using Weblogic workshop 8.1, JPF framework (similar to Struts), JDK 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Its a lot easier if you convert it to JSON. I understand that you dont want to send json object from your server, but you can convert your map(or any datastructure) to json on the client side.

The working code for your problem : [DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxX9a/3/)

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataFromJava = "{3=003:Ackon Gonsalves:Ackon@email.com, 2=002:Abraham Gonsalves:Abraham@email.com, 1=001:Aaron Gonsalves:Aaron@email.com}";
    parseMap(dataFromJava);
    var data = parseMap(dataFromJava);
    $("#example").autocomplete({
        source: data,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#example").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#emp_id").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#email").val(ui.item.email);

            return false;
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $("#emp_id").val('');
            $("#email").val('');
        }
    });
});

function parseMap(data) {
    //Remove { and }
    data = data.substring(1, data.length - 1);
    var rows = data.split(',');
    var result = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var value = rows[i].split("=")[1];
        var variables = value.split(":");
        result[i] = {};
        result[i]['value'] = variables[0];
        result[i]['label'] = variables[1];
        result[i]['email'] = variables[2];
    }
    return result;
}​
function submitValue() {

    var name = $("#example").val();
    var id = $("#emp_id").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    alert(id + ":" + name + ":" + email);
}
</script>​
```

Also use the latest versions of Jquery & Jquery-UI (Or Jquery Autocomplete) plugins..